# Cannot get SDSF to respond to TSO or batch commands

Tags: mainframe, zos, sdsf

I am trying to write a JCL Job Step that will retrieve the JESMSGLG, JESJCL, and JESLOG datasets of the active (this) job. The idea here is that I need to collect the log (from the beginning of the job to now) and record it in a data set before it ends execution.
So I have:

```
// EXEC PGM=SDSF
//MYOUT DD SYSOUT=*   (to changed to a dataset in the future)
//ISFOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//ISFIN DD *
SET CONSOLE BATCH
PREFIX *
OWNER myid
DA OJOB
++S
PRINT FILE MYOUT
FIND JESMSGLG FIRST
++X
FIND JESJCL FIRST
++X
FIND JESLOG FIRST
++X
PRINT CLOSE
```

When I run the job all I get is CC=0000 and a printout of the SDSF Primary panel in IFSOUT.

If I try this under TSO with the SDSF command, again, all I get is the primary panel. If I enter *any* command (even an invalid one) it just seems to take the command and silently ignore it.

I can do this under ISPF just fine.

Any ideas as to what to look for to see what I am doing wrong or missing? Its pretty clear to me that this may well be a setup/invocation/security issue but I don't know how to debug it when all I seem to get is CC=0000.

Comment: When you say “I can do this under ISPF just fine”, do you mean go into SDSF and run this commands, or run a job?  And when you submit the job, it it a single step job (ie, just this step), or are there steps before it?

Comment: If I log into TSO and use ISPF I can do things like =S;DA and can see my TSO Session and any jobs that I might have running, queued, and ny SYSOUT datasets. Everything about SDSF runs as expected.  I can also submit jobs just fine and watch them execute.

If I start SDSF directly at the TSO Ready prompt (not under ISPF)  all I get is the primary panel and it seems to ignore all my input commands.  This also happens with PGM=SDSF in JCL.   For the sake of simpliticpty assume that I have an // EXEC PGM=IEFBR14 before the // EXEC PGM=SDSF

Comment: Also, I am able to access SDSF via IFSEXEC with a TSO REXX script. The issue (for me) is that this MUST be run as a batch job step for reasons that I may not disclose. What I am trying to do is my preferred solution (if I can get it to work). If not then I'll have to try ISFEXEC under REXX under IKJEFT01 but would rather not invest the time to do that.

Comment: On a lark I logged into TSO with an "ordinary" 43x80 3270 screen and the TSO-only version of SDSF came to life!  I recalled that the manual said something along the lines of "strange things can happen with odd screen sizes."  I was using a 50x132 display.  As I recall there is a screen size option available on the PGM=SDSF version.  I'll check into that but I think I might be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that was it!   I added PARM='++24,80' to the // EXEC PGM=SDSF and it now works. I'm not entirely sure why but it may have been a local installation error of SDSF.

It turns out the the commands I listed above are not quite right, but that's not relevant to this question.

Thank you, Kevin, for your time and interest.